# Webpack dll import is not defined

Tags: node.js, dll, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to put a bunch of libs on the DLL following guides like [react-boilerplate](https://medium.com/@soederpop/webpack-plugins-been-we-been-keepin-on-the-dll-cdfdd6cb8cd7) and [this one](https://robertknight.me.uk/posts/webpack-dll-plugins/).

When I build and run, the DLL files are given as not defined.
I'm probably missing something I did a separated webpack to build the dll:

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
const library = '[name]'
export default {
  entry: {
    'lokka': ['lokka', 'lokka-transport-http', 'socket.io-client']
    /** Other libs **/
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].dll.js',
    path: 'build/',
    library: library
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllPlugin({
      path: 'build/[name]-manifest.json',
      name: library
    })
  ]
}
```

And added the references to the manifest.json

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
const desiredLibs = [
  'lokka'
]
const plugins = desiredLibs.map((lib) => {
  return new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
    context: process.cwd(),
    manifest: require(`../build/${lib}-manifest.json`)
  })
})
export const dllReference = () => {
  return { plugins }
}
export default dllReference
```

Was there anything else I should do?

On my case, it is complaining that lokka is not found when the code is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I (obviously) need to include the generated DLL on my scripts src AND copy it in the case of dev, since hot reloading would only serve the entry of it and it's dependencies, so for the dllReference and copy part it became:

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin'
import path from 'path'

const desiredLibs = ['lokka', 'react', 'moment']
const copies = []
const plugins = desiredLibs.map((lib) => {
  copies.push({
    from: path.join(__dirname, `../compileResources/${lib}.dll.js`),
    to: `dll`
  })
  return new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
    context: process.cwd(),
    manifest: require(`../compileResources/${lib}-manifest.json`)
  })
})
plugins.push(
  new CopyWebpackPlugin(copies)
)
/**
* Adds the dll references and copies the file
*/
export const dllReference = () => {
  return { plugins }
}
export default dllReference
```

And then since I copied the dll's using the copy plugin I needed to add the scripts on the html. Really obvious on hindsight